# Eclipse deploying between 2 Sandboxes

Tags: ide

Im getting the following error when trying to deploy a number of items from a dev to a full sandbox.

[image]

Works ok if i just deploy a couple of components at a time but if i try to deploy all changes it throws this. Any ideas?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Try to use Ant script for the big deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrowed it down to a single object. Contacted support, they suggested trying change sets which worked for that particular object. Hasn't resolved the problem in Eclipse, but can live with using change sets for that one object as i dont make too many changes.

Comment: Awesome!  Can you share what the problem was with the object (e.g., too many X, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

From the [API ExceptionCode listing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421192):

> LIMIT_EXCEEDED An array is too long. For example, there are too many
>   BCC addresses, targets, or email messages.

So, maybe you have a large number of something in your metadata that isn't being handled by the API in a nice way.  Maybe you can narrow it down to an individual component.

The underlying error is a Java exception that appears to be generated from calling a stored procedure.  I would contact Salesforce support. Anytime you see a Java error it is not a bad idea to do that.  Especially, in this case because you aren't actually using the API in your own custom way.  If you do so, and get an answer back please post the answer here if you can.